# How to change fontsize of scale of axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to change fontsize of my matplotlib.pyplot graph and I figured out how to change fontsize of label, ticks. But I still don't know when y scale is so small, how to change scale fontsize (such as 1e-17 at the following image) which indicate the scale on the top left of the figure. Is any option to make this possible in matplotlib.pyplot?

here's my example code.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(0, 1e-8, 1e-9)

plt.figure(figsize = (10,6))
plt.plot(a,a**2)
plt.xticks(fontsize = 30)
plt.yticks(fontsize = 30)
```

with several command, I can change fontsize of x, y ticks, but I cannot find the command for scale fontsize.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do it by setting default font-size, as follows:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.rc('font', size=30) # This line makes it work!

a = np.arange(0, 1e-8, 1e-9)
plt.figure(figsize = (10,6))
plt.plot(a,a**2)
plt.xticks(fontsize = 30)
plt.yticks(fontsize = 30)
plt.show()
```

[image]